# Split overlapping ranges into all unique ranges

Tags: scala, date-range

I am trying to split a dynamic number of ranges with associated attributes, so that whenever 2 or more ranges overlap, the overlapping section(s) are split into unique ranges with the combination of all overlapping attributes.

datasets are of type

```
case class testCC(bgn_ts: java.sql.Timestamp, end_ts: java.sql.Timestamp, supply1: Int, supply2: Int)
```

Now data dataset1 will always have supply2 as 0 and dataset2 will always have supply 1 as 0.

```
                         Set1                                    
bgn_ts            | end_ts            |  supply1   |supply2 |    
2020-12-13T11:45  | 2020-12-16T11:45  | 10         |  0     |    
2020-12-16T11:45  | 9999-12-31T00:00  | 11         |  0     |

                         Set2
bgn_ts            | end_ts            |  supply1   |supply2 | 
2020-12-15T11:45  | 9999-12-31T00:00  | 0          |  12    |
```

This should result in

```
bgn_ts            | end_ts            |  supply1   |supply2 |
2020-12-13T11:45  | 2020-12-15T11:45  |   10       |  0     |
2020-12-15T11:45  | 2020-12-16T11:45  |   10       |  12    |
2020-12-16T11:45  | 9999-12-31T00:00  |   11       |  12    |
```

Another example:

```
                         Set1                                    
bgn_ts            | end_ts            |  supply1   |supply2 |    
2020-12-13T11:45  | 2020-12-16T11:45  | 10         |  0     |    
2020-12-16T11:45  | 2020-12-17T11:45  | 12         |  0     |
2020-12-17T11:45  | 9999-12-31T00:00  | 20         |  0     |

                         Set2                                    
bgn_ts            | end_ts            |  supply1   |supply2 |    
2020-12-13T11:45  | 2020-12-15T11:45  | 0          | 10     |    
2020-12-15T11:45  | 2020-12-16T11:45  | 0          |  9     |
2020-12-16T11:45  | 2020-12-18T11:45  | 0          | 12     |
2020-12-18T11:45  | 9999-12-31T00:00  | 0          | 21     |
```

This should result in

```
bgn_ts            | end_ts            |  supply1   |supply2 |    
2020-12-13T11:45  | 2020-12-15T11:45  | 10         | 10     |    
2020-12-15T11:45  | 2020-12-16T11:45  | 10         |  9     |
2020-12-16T11:45  | 2020-12-17T11:45  | 12         | 12     |
2020-12-17T11:45  | 2020-12-18T11:45  | 20         | 12     |
2020-12-18T11:45  | 9999-12-31T00:00  | 20         | 21     |
```

Below is the code I tried:

```
implicit def ts_ordering: Ordering[Timestamp] = new Ordering[Timestamp] {
            override def compare(x: Timestamp, y: Timestamp): Int = x compareTo y
          }

set2.sortBy(_.end_ts)
.foldLeft(set1.sortBy(_.end_ts)) {
  case (result, set2_entry) =>
    result.span(!_.end_ts.after(set2_entry.bgn_ts)) match {
      case (before, remaining) =>
        val (overlap, after) = remaining.span(_.bgn_ts.before(set2_entry.end_ts))
        before ++ (
          overlap.flatMap {
            case o if o.bgn_ts.equals(set2_entry.bgn_ts) && o.end_ts.equals(set2_entry.end_ts) =>
              o.copy(supply2 = set2_entry.supply2) :: Nil
            case o if o.bgn_ts.before(set2_entry.bgn_ts) && o.end_ts.after(set2_entry.end_ts) =>
              // need to split into three here, set2 record is entirely within this record
              o.copy(end_ts = set2_entry.bgn_ts) ::
              o.copy(bgn_ts = set2_entry.bgn_ts, end_ts = set2_entry.end_ts, supply2 = set2_entry.supply2) ::
              o.copy(bgn_ts = set2_entry.end_ts) ::
              Nil
            case o if !o.bgn_ts.after(set2_entry.bgn_ts) =>
              // split into two here, set2 record overlaps after the beginning of this record
              o.copy(end_ts = set2_entry.bgn_ts) ::
              o.copy(bgn_ts = set2_entry.bgn_ts, supply2 = set2_entry.supply2) ::
              Nil
            case o =>
              // split into two here, set2 record overlaps before the end of this record
              o.copy(end_ts = set2_entry.end_ts, supply2 = set2_entry.supply2) ::
              o.copy(bgn_ts = set2_entry.end_ts) ::
              Nil
          }
        ) ++ after
    }
}
```

To make it easier for testing, I'm supplying the test data:

```
Example1
val set1 = List(
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-13 11:45:00"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-16 11:45:00"), supply2 = 0, supply1 = 10),
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-16 11:45:00"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("9999-12-31 00:00:00"), supply2 = 0, supply1 = 11)
)

val set2 = List(
  testCC(
    bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-15 11:45:00"),
    end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("9999-12-31 00:00:00"), supply1 = 0, supply2 = 12)
)

val expected1 = List(
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-13 11:45:00.0"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-15 11:45:00.0"), supply1 = 10, supply2 = 0),
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-15 11:45:00.0"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-16 11:45:00.0"), supply1 = 10, supply2 = 12),
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-16 11:45:00.0"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("9999-12-31 00:00:00"), supply1 = 11, supply2 = 12)
    )


Example2
val set1 = List(
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-13 11:45:00"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-16 11:45:00"), supply2 = 0, supply1 = 10),
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-16 11:45:00"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-17 11:45:00"), supply2 = 0, supply1 = 12),
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-17 11:45:00"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("9999-12-31 00:00:00"), supply2 = 0, supply1 = 20)
    )

val set2 = List(
  testCC(
    bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-13 11:45:00"),
    end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-15 11:45:00"), supply1 = 0, supply2 = 10),
  testCC(
    bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-15 11:45:00"),
    end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-16 11:45:00"), supply1 = 0, supply2 = 9),
  testCC(
    bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-16 11:45:00"),
    end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-18 11:45:00"), supply1 = 0, supply2 = 12),
  testCC(
    bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-18 11:45:00"),
    end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("9999-12-31 00:00:00"), supply1 = 0, supply2 = 21)
)

val expected1 = List(
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-13 11:45:00.0"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-15 11:45:00.0"), supply1 = 10, supply2 = 10),
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-15 11:45:00.0"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-16 11:45:00.0"), supply1 = 10, supply2 = 9),
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-16 11:45:00.0"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-17 11:45:00.0"), supply1 = 12, supply2 = 12),
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-17 11:45:00.0"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-18 11:45:00.0"), supply1 = 20, supply2 = 12),
      testCC(
        bgn_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-12-18 11:45:00.0"),
        end_ts = Timestamp.valueOf("9999-12-31 00:00:00"), supply1 = 20, supply2 = 21)
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work for the 2 test examples provided.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class TestCC(bgn_ts: Timestamp, end_ts: Timestamp
                 ,supply1: Int, supply2: Int)

def mergeRanges(lst1: List[TestCC]
               ,lst2: List[TestCC]): List[TestCC] = {
  val lsts = lst1 ++ lst2
  val bMap = lsts.groupMapReduce(_.bgn_ts)(identity){
    case (a,b) => TestCC(a.bgn_ts, b.end_ts
                        ,a.supply1+b.supply1, a.supply2+b.supply2)
  }
  val eMap = lsts.groupMapReduce(_.end_ts)(identity){
    case (a,b) => TestCC(a.bgn_ts, b.end_ts
                        ,a.supply1+b.supply1, a.supply2+b.supply2)
  }
  List.unfold(bMap.keys.toList.sorted ->
              eMap.keys.toList.sorted){
    case (Nil, Nil) => None
    case (Nil,_)|(_,Nil) => throw new Error("unexpected")
    case (b::bs, e::es) =>
      if (bs.nonEmpty && bs.head.before(e))
        Some(bMap(b).copy(end_ts = bs.head) -> (bs,e::es))
      else
        Some(TestCC(b, e
                   ,bMap(b).supply1 max eMap(e).supply1
                   ,bMap(b).supply2 max eMap(e).supply2) -> (bs,es))
  }
}
```

The code makes a few assumptions about the input data and I'm not sure how well it will handle malformed input, but give it a try and see if it gets you closer to your goal.

---

### **2nd attempt**

After thinking it over I decided that a different approach was required.

```
def mergeRanges(lst1: List[TestCC]
               ,lst2: List[TestCC]): List[TestCC] = {
  val lsts = lst1 ++ lst2
  val s1Map = lsts.filter(_.supply1 > 0)
                  .sortBy(_.bgn_ts)
                  .foldLeft(Map.empty[Timestamp,Int]){
                    case (mp, TestCC(b,e,s1,_)) =>
                      mp + (b -> s1) + (e -> s1)
                  }.withDefaultValue(0)
  val s1Lst = s1Map.keys.toList.sorted.reverse
  val s2Map = lsts.filter(_.supply2 > 0)
                  .sortBy(_.bgn_ts)
                  .foldLeft(Map.empty[Timestamp,Int]){
                    case (mp, TestCC(b,e,_,s2)) =>
                      mp + (b -> s2) + (e -> s2)
                  }.withDefaultValue(0)
  val s2Lst = s2Map.keys.toList.sorted.reverse
  lsts.flatMap{case TestCC(b,e,_,_) => List(b,e)}
      .distinct.sorted.sliding(2).toList
      .map{case List(ts1, ts2) =>
        TestCC(ts1, ts2
          ,s1Lst.dropWhile(_.after(ts1)).headOption.fold(0)(s1Map)
          ,s2Lst.dropWhile(_.after(ts1)).headOption.fold(0)(s2Map))
      }
}
```

I believe this passes all *current* test examples.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh. this is a good way at looking at the problem. However there is a slight gap here:
for ex if there is a complete overlap of one record inside another, this logic will break.
rec1: 12T -> 99T: (0, 11)
rec2: 13T -> 16T : (10, 0)
         16T -> 99T : (8,0)
Result : 12T -> 13T : (0, 11)
             13T -> 16T : (10, 0) [should be (10,11)]
             16T -> 99T : (8, 11)

Comment: Thanks again @jwvh for the 2nd pass. was kind of late last night, hence didn't post my take on the problem. Posted it now, looks like we were on similar lines of thinking. Would love to know, what do you think of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, kind of similar to @jwvh's line of thinking. Instead of using maps, I am putting the event in a Set

```
case class Event(offset: Timestamp, isEnd: Boolean, supply1: Int, supply2: Int)
case class CoreData(supply1: Int, supply2: Int)

def createEventsFromSymbol(x: TestCC): List[Event] = {
    Event(x.bgn_ts, isEnd = false, x.supply1, x.supply2) ::
    Event(x.end_ts, isEnd = true, x.supply1, x.supply2) :: Nil
}
val lst = ats ++ inv

val events = lst
      .flatMap(createEventsFromSymbol)
      .sortBy(x => (x.offset, x.isEnd))

val defaultTs = Timestamp.valueOf("1970-01-01 00:00:00.0")

val (result1, _, _) =
    events.foldLeft(List.empty[InvAts], defaultTs, List.empty[CoreData]){

      case ((result, currentStart, currentSet), currentEvent) =>
        if(currentEvent.isEnd) {
          val mergedEvent =
            if(!currentStart.equals(defaultTs) && currentEvent.offset.after(currentStart)) {
              val coreData: CoreData = currentSet
                .reduce((a, b) => CoreData(a.current_supply + b.current_supply, a.available_to_sell + b.available_to_sell))

              TestCC(currentStart, currentEvent.offset, x.current_supply, x.available_to_sell) :: Nil
            }
            else {
              Nil
            }

            val new_set = currentSet
                .filterNot(x =>  x.current_supply == currentEvent.current_supply && x.available_to_sell == currentEvent.available_to_sell)

            (mergedEvent ++ result, currentEvent.offset, new_set)
        }
        else {
            val mergedEvent =
            if (!currentStart.equals(defaultTs) && !currentEvent.offset.equals(currentStart) && currentEvent.offset.after(currentStart)) {
              val x = currentSet
                .reduce((a, b) => CoreData(a.current_supply + b.current_supply, a.available_to_sell + b.available_to_sell))

              TestCC(currentStart, currentEvent.offset, x.current_supply, x.available_to_sell) :: Nil
            }
            else {
              Nil
            }

            val new_set = (CoreData(currentEvent.current_supply, currentEvent.available_to_sell) :: currentSet).distinct
            (mergedEvent ++ result, currentEvent.offset, new_set)
        }
    }
```